# "Criticism" vs. "critique"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

What is the difference in meaning between *criticism* and *critique*?

Comment: Also on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critique#Critique_vs_Criticism

Comment: @Pacerier in reading academic texts I see the differentiation above often doesn't apply. It depends on the field, but at least in the social/political sciences, writers can use *critique* in the sense of criticism just as much as *criticism* itself is.

At least from what I already read, the only field in which the distinction above is consistently verified is philosophy.

In other fields, the use of *critique* in the sense of *detailed analysis* often verifies in older texts (100+ years). Texts from the 20th/21st century often use the terms interchangeably.

Comment: In other words, I think this differentiation on wikipedia is a bit purist for today's standard, critique is often used in the sense of *criticism*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At bottom there is no difference.

The terms *critic*, *criticize*, *criticism* have always had a double sense in English. The base meaning is “pass judgment on”, but in popular use the words have usually meant “pass a negative judgment on”, while in academic and literary use they have tended in the opposite direction, signifying close and dispassionate analysis which may or may not issue in a formal judgment.

The French version *critique* was adopted into English primarily as a noun, meaning an instance of criticism, a critical essay or notice; in many cases there is no evident distinction between *critic(k)* and *critique* in this sense until the 19th century. Around 1960 academics began using *critique* in both nominal and verbal senses more and more frequently—at a guess, as a desperate effort to drive into thick undergraduate heads the fact that the critical endeavour in literature, art, history and philosophy is **not** simply a matter of expressing negative opinions.

If that was the intention, it failed. Today *critique* in popular use is just as likely to mean ‘censure’ as ‘analyze’.

> “Maybe we should be that way about the first gentleman also and really critique the way they look all the time, their choice of tie, or their hair style or whatever, or maybe their weight.” —Former first lady Laura Bush on [CSPAN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpKhvM3nJ-Y), Jan 27 2014
>
> Yes, to hell with all of these left communists making criticisms! For as we all know the left has never done anything worth of critique! —Comment on a book review on [The North Star](http://www.thenorthstar.info/?p=11991#comment-1340060581), Apr 5 2014
>
> **Funding freeze critiqued** A UK science-advocacy group says that a repeated freeze to the government's £4.6-billion (US$7-billion) science-research budget, announced on 26 June, will damage early-career researchers' work and drive them to other nations. —[*Nature* online](http://www.nature.com/naturejobs/science/articles/10.1038/nj7456-117c), 2013

Comment: He asked for meaning, not an etymological discussion and faulty prose from people without the necessary esoteric logic to formulate coherent structure. "You have to understand that people that are hurting are going to criticize."
George H. W. Bush, Former President  (Giggle!  It is fun to comment like that!)

Comment: @APrejean I don't think you can characterize either Ms. Bush, an admirably articulate woman, or the editorial staff of one of the world's most prestigious academic journals, as lacking in logical discrimination. I have apparently not made myself clear: there **are** two meanings involved here, but they distinguish not two words, but the use of both words for different audiences.

Answer (score 0):

"Critique" is mainly used when literature or a work of art is concerned. "Criticism" is the general word.

Answer (score 0):

I had a teacher for Equine and Animal science that was a real hard ass, but I loved her very much. She always said to people "I'm not criticizing you, I'm critiquing you" 
In other words she wasnt trying to hurt someone with everything they did wrong, she was pointing out specifically the things they needed to work on and how to do so. Even if it sounded harsh I believe critiquing always involves some sort of advice or reasoning to help a person grow from mistakes. While critics just say there opinion on how things are wrong. Whether it's what you say, do, how you write, think etc.

Answer (score -1):

http://scribesalley.blogspot.com/2008/08/difference-between-critique-and.html

> The Difference between Critique and Criticism
>
> ```
> Criticism finds fault/Critique looks at structure
> Criticism looks for what's lacking/Critique finds what's working
> Criticism condemns what it doesn't understand/Critique asks for clarification
> Criticism is spoken with a cruel wit and sarcastic tongue/Critique's voice is kind, honest, and objective
> Criticism is negative/Critique is positive (even about what isn't working)
> Criticism is vague and general/Critique is concrete and specific
> Criticism has no sense of humor/Critique insists on laughter, too
> Criticism looks for flaws in the writer as well as the writing/Critique addresses only what is on the page
> ```
>
> Taken from Writing Alone, Writing Together; A Guide for Writers and
>   Writing Groups by Judy Reeves

Comment: This is an entirely idiolectal understanding of the terms which bears no relation to their actual use.

Comment: If you all are going to pout about the answer because it is a quote, that is fine.  But Judy Reeves and her published work are quite accepted and accredited, and this was her guide to use, not meaning.  Your fiction was stated quite pleasantly, though.

Comment: I have no objections to quotations - I employ them myself. But Ms. Reeves describes herself as "writer, teacher, and writing practice provocateur", and I think this is one of her provocations, not serious criticism/critique.

Comment: @StoneyB Even with your mischaracterization of her work, by your own quote it was "writing practice provocateur".  She did not outline the difference in meaning (which OP requested) for a philosophical soliloquy, but for other people to use in their writing.  At worst, you disagree with her, but thumbing me down on a post that has EXACT application to the question posed was improper.  I gave an appropriate source and was on-topic.  The OP may not be better off for my post, but you cannot argue that he is worse off for it, either.

Answer (score -2):

criticize is like when u know your kids talk something bad about someone not exactly backbiting but like

> when he went to syria he saw people criticizing hazrat ali

criticize is talking bad about someone you know i dont care if thats not the correct answer cause i am just typing like crazy

critique means to censure/analyze

Comment: Your response would be more effective if you quoted and linked to third-party resources (such as dictionaries) that corroborate for the definitions you provide.